# Flatten pyspark nested structure - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, data-structures, pyspark

I want to flatten a nested column into separate ones, containing only a few specific values.

First off, I start with an AVRO capture file from Event hub. Once I convert that to a dataframe in python, I receive the following column after removing the irrelevant ones.

[image: Converted AVRO nested structure]

This column has the following structure.
[image: Column structure]

What I want to do next, is flatten this column remaining specific values.

I can get this done for one cell, but because I am dealing with a nested structure the column is not iterable.

Anyone can help me out?

[image: Result]

Comment: I don't see any `speed` or `timestamp` in your input data and schema?

Comment: Excuse me,
Speed and Timestamp are representing struct elements: "a" and "time".
As shown on the 4th and 5th line of the structure picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `data` fields in your schema so I'd call the first one `data_struct` and the second one `data_array`. If you do `avro_df_body.select('data_struct.data_array')`, you'd have an `ArrayType` column, which you can apply [`explode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) function to break it down to multiple rows.

```py
(avro_df_body
    .withColumn('tmp', F.explode('data_struct.data_array'))
    .withColumn('speed', F.col('tmp.a'))
    .withColumn('timestamp', F.col('tmp.time'))
    .show()
)
```